# Can't get MVC MiniProfiler to show on ASP.net website

Tags: asp.net, mvc-mini-profiler

My web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Content/ErrorPages/500.aspx" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Content/ErrorPages/404.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpModules>
      <add type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" name="UrlRewriter" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <rewriter configSource="Config\URLRewrites.config" />
  <appSettings configSource="Config\Settings.config" />
    <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
            <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" path="/Content/ErrorPages/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="500" path="/Content/ErrorPages/500.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
          <remove name="UrlRewriter" />
          <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule,Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        </modules>
      <handlers>
        <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>    
</configuration>
```

My global.asax:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using StackExchange.Profiling;

namespace C3
{
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Force to HTTPS
            if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection)
            {
                Response.Redirect(Settings.SecureRootDomain + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
            }

            if (Request.IsLocal)
            {
                MiniProfiler.Start();
            } 
        }

        protected void Application_EndRequest()
        {
            MiniProfiler.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Content page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="C3.Default"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="C3.Code" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="StackExchange.Profiling" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <%
        SEO.CheckURL("/");
    %>
    <title></title>
    <%=MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes() %>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        dum de dum
    </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

And code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var profiler = MiniProfiler.Current; // it's ok if this is null
    using (profiler.Step("Set page title"))
    {
        Page.Title = "Home Page";
    }
    using (profiler.Step("Doing complex stuff"))
    {
        using (profiler.Step("Step A"))
        { // something more interesting here
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        using (profiler.Step("Step B"))
        { // and here
            Thread.Sleep(250);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why the MiniProfiler isn't showing anything?

**Update**

If I visit `https://127.0.0.1:3333/mini-profiler-resources/includes.js` in my browser, it's returning the JS file!  It's just not rendering the includes on the page itself.

If I visit `/mini-profiler-resources/results` it throws the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   StackExchange.Profiling.MiniProfilerHandler.GetSingleProfilerResult(HttpContext
>   context) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\1de24adb938b932d\StackExchange.Profiling\MiniProfilerHandler.cs:292
>   StackExchange.Profiling.MiniProfilerHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\1de24adb938b932d\StackExchange.Profiling\MiniProfilerHandler.cs:93
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +912    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +164

Comment: Did you see this github issue? The exception is thrown exactly the same way. https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/issues/96

Comment: @Andrei yes have seen that, if I add it in it stops the 500 exception but now returns a 404.  Includes still not being rendered on the page either.

Comment: I'd say 500 -> 400 is an improvement. It might be the case that something else is also wrong, but I'd keep this fix

Comment: @Andrei yeah you're probably right.  Searched Google for hours, not entirely sure where to go next with this issue

Comment: Going forward, all examples I found so far had jquery on the page registered already. You don't have one. It should not be an issue really, but just out of curiosity try passing into `RenderIncludes` the param `useExistingjQuery:false`

Comment: check this url: http://miniprofiler.com/ , I believe same method as mentioned in the answer below

Comment: @Andrei param makes no difference

Comment: @HadiHassan used `for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) { Response.Write(i); }`, no difference nothing rendering

Comment: Can you check to see whether `MiniProfiler.Current` has a value or if it's null in `Page_Load`?

Comment: @Hack, it's `null` after started in global.asax, before I stop it in global.asax, and on the content page (null everywhere!)

Comment: @TomGullen, what's the full URL to that Default.aspx page? Does it happen to have /content/ in the URL, e.g. /content/Default.aspx?

Comment: @Hack, the URL in the browser is `https://127.0.0.1:3333/` but it's rewritten with the rule `<rewrite url="^/(\?(.+))?$" to="~/Content/Default.aspx$1" processing="stop"/>`.  Is the `Content` directory causing some sort of conflict?

Comment: @Hack, you're a genius!  Renamed the folder to `Pages` and it works!  Please write this as an answer and I'll accept it :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure pages showing the MiniProfiler don't contain an ignored path in the URL specified by `MiniProfiler.Settings.IgnoredPaths`, which by default has `/content/`, `/scripts/` and `/favicon.ico`. A page with the URL `/content/Default.aspx` won't show the MiniProfiler, whereas `/Pages/Default.aspx` will show it.

Alternatively, remove `/content/` from `MiniProfiler.Settings.IgnoredPaths`.